# Why Krishna allowed Bhima to kill Dushashan in brutal manner?

Tags: mahabharata

Bhima killed Dushashan mercilessly. Bhima drank his blood.
Why Krishna allowed such act ?

Is this episode of Bhima drinking blood of Dushashan correct written in Mahabharat ?

Why Krishna allowed such brutal act ?

Was such practice dharma in those times ?

For example-
Death sentence or more brutal punishment was to be given for crimes which are considered as small in present times. But in those times it was normal.
As It was dharma in those times.

Is there justification given for such thing ?
Was it due to some other secret reason ?

Comment: Dushasan tried to disrobe Draupadi. I think that's one of the reasons why he was put to death in such a manner.

Comment: Also it would likely burn up a good amount of his bad karma

Answer (score 2):

> Bhima killed Dushashan mercilessly. Bhima drank his blood. Why Krishna allowed such act ?

It was the vow taken by Bhima to avenge the disrobing of Draupadi.

[Mbh Sabhaparva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02067.htm)

> And Bhima said,--Hear these words of mine, ye Kshatriyas of the world. **Words such as these were never before uttered by other men, nor will anybody in the future ever utter them.** Ye lords of earth, if having spoken these words I do not accomplish them hereafter, let me not obtain the region of my deceased ancestors. **Tearing open in battle, by sheer force, the breast of this wretch (Dushasana), this wicked-minded scoundrel of the Bharata race, if I do not drink his life-blood, let me not obtain the region of my ancestors."**

> Was such practice dharma in those times ?

From Bhima's words above, it is also clear that this is an unusual vow.

> Is this episode of Bhima drinking blood of Dushashan correct written in Mahabharat ?

Yes, it is mentioned in Karnaparva.

[Mbh Karnaparva](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08083.htm)

> Bhima, having slain there (at the very sight of Karna) the vindictive Duhshasana, took up a little quantity of his blood, and, endued with stentorian lungs, he said these words in the hearing of all those foremost of heroes of the world, **"O wretch amongst men, here I drink thy life-blood from thy throat.** Filled with joy, abuse us once more, saying 'beast, beast' (as thou didst before)." And he continued, "They that danced at us then, saying, 'beast, beast,' even we will dance at them now, repeating their own words. **Our sleep at the palace at Pramanakoti, the administration of deadly poison to our food, the bites of black cobras, the setting fire to the house of lac, the robbing of our kingdom by gambling, our exile in the woods, the cruel seizure of Draupadi's beautiful tresses, the strokes of shafts and weapons in battle, our miseries at home, the other kinds of sufferings we endured at Virata's abode, all these woes borne by us through the counsels of Shakuni and Duryodhana and Radha's son, proceeded from thee (Dushasana) as their cause.** Through the wickedness of Dhritarashtra and his son, we have endured all these woes. Happiness has never been ours." Having said these words, O king, the victorious Vrikodara, once more spoke these words unto Keshava and Arjuna. Indeed, bathed in blood, with blood flowing from his wounds, with face exceedingly red, filled with great wrath, Bhimasena endued with great activity, said these words, **"Ye heroes, that which I had vowed in respect of Duhshasana in battle, I have accomplished today.**

> Why Krishna allowed such brutal act ?

Because it was Bhima's vow.

Comment: The more I read about Hinduism, the more I am surprised how amoral Hinduism often becomes.

Comment: Understanding action, evil action and inaction requires knowledge. What's moral some may find immoral... through avidya.